# get files from directory based on substring of filename - C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# console app which gets all files in a directory.  Taking the file name below as an example, and given that I will have 3 strings, ref, year1, year2, how could I say:

File name: `31596_2015-06-30.pdf`

Give me all files where the file name contain ref AND file name contains a year between year1 and year 2?
Code so far:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                          .Select(Path.GetFileName);

string start_year = null;
string end_year = null;
string ref = null;

// dr is a sql data reader
if (dr.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        start_year = dr.GetString(1).Substring(7, 4);
        end_year = dr.GetString(2).Substring(7, 4);
        ref = dr.GetString(3);

        foreach(string filename in files)
        {
            if (filename.Contains(ref)) 
            {
                File.Copy(sourceDir + filename, targetDir + filename);
            }
        }

        File.Copy(sourceDir + dr.GetString(0), targetDir + dr.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: See edit, dr is a datareader

Comment: ref is a keyword so I would highly suggest finding a better name for that variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest *extracting a class*, say, `FileData`:

```
public class FileData {
  public bool IsParsed {get; private set; }

  public String FileName {get; private set; }

  public DateTime Date {get; private set; }

  public String Ref {get; private set; }

  public FileData(String path) {
    FileName = path;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
      return;

    int p = path.IndexOf('_');

    if (p < 0)
      return;

    Ref = path.Substring(0, p);

    DateTime dt;

    IsParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(path.Substring(p + 1), 
      "yyyy-MM-dd", 
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
      DateTimeStyles.None, 
     out dt);

    Date = dt;
  }
}
```

By doing this you can put a simple *Linq* to obtain the files

```
  var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(sourceDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(file => new FileData(file))
    .Where(info => info.IsParsed)
    .Where(info => String.Equals(info.Ref, myRef))
    .Where(info => info.Date.Year >= year1 && info.Date.Year <= year2)
    .Select(info => info.FileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your filenames have always the format as in your post,
you first need to split the year out of the name.
One possible solution could be:

```
 string filenameYear = filename.Split('_')[1].Split('-')[0];
```

then you can use this string in your if condition to ask for all three cases:

```
if (filename.Contains(_ref) &&
    Convert.ToInt32(filenameYear) > Convert.ToInt32(start_year) &&
    Convert.ToInt32(filenameYear) < Convert.ToInt32(end_year))
{
    // Do what ever you desire

}
```

in the line:

```
File.Copy(sourceDir + filename, targetDir + filename);
```

If  `sourceDir` and `targetDir`  has not a `\` in the end or `filename` in the beginning. This will crash.
You can use

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir,filename), Path.combine(targetDir, filename);
```

to avoid problems

ps. you should avoid using `ref` as a name for variables in C#.
it is reserved as a [keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I like Linq for this sort of thing.  Unless you know for a fact that the values in the reader will always by what you expect, you should perform some validations, but this will achieve your stated goal with the least amount of changes to your sample code.

```
    var start_year = (DateTime)dr.GetString(1).Substring(7, 4);
    var end_year = (DateTime)dr.GetString(2).Substring(7, 4);
    ref = dr.GetString(3);

    foreach(string filename in files.Where(x => x.StartsWith(ref) 
                    && (DateTime)x.Substring(7, 4) >= start_year 
                    && (DateTime)x.Substring(7, 4) <= end_year))
    {
        File.Copy(sourceDir + filename, targetDir + filename);
    }
```